# Getting false for is_home() on Posts page

Tags: conditional-tags, conditional-content

I've made a child theme of Twenty Twenty theme and want to display the posts/ category archive pages in [flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/csS/css3_flexbox.asp) grid.

However, none of the [conditional tags](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/conditional-tags/) I'm hoping to check outside the loop ([is_home](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_home/), [is_archive](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_archive/), [is_category](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_category/)) are returning true on posts page or category archive pages:

```
* @since Twenty Twenty 1.0
*/
get_header();
?>

<?php if ( is_archive() ): ?>
    <h1>ARCHIVE</h1>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ( is_category() ): ?>
    <h1>CATEGORY</h1>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ( is_home() ): ?>
    <h1>HOME</h1>
<?php endif; ?>

<main id="site-content maybe-flex-directive-class-here">

    <?php

    if ( have_posts() ) {

        while ( have_posts() ) {
            the_post();
```

I expect either I'm missing something obvious or going about it the wrong way.

Comment: Which template file does this code reside in?

Comment: it's in `singular.php`

Comment: which makes the answer really obvious! I wasn't seeing that the theme includes `<main id="site-content">` on `index.php` as well as `singular.php`. I think I will delete this post unless you feel like posting an answer. Please lmk.

Comment: Naw that's cool - you can delete :P. Always keep our friendly [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) close at hand!

Comment: Thanks and peace man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was going to (and actually did) delete this post, but after sleeping on it, think it might end up being of some use.

What I was missing, above, is [Template Hierarchy][1]. I was looking at the `singular.php` template file, which will *only* ever be loaded when `is_archive()`, `is_home()`, etc, aren't true.

What got me is that the HTML `<main>` element exists on both the `index.php` and `singular.php` documents in this theme.

So I was able to update the child theme's copy of `index.php`:

```
<main id="site-content" class="flex-container">
```

With CSS:

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
/* Responsive layout - make multi-column on larger screens */
@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .flex-container {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}
```

Thanks for the solution in the comment, @bosco.

```
  [1]: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/
```